# Distortion in demodulation signal

Tags: modulation, demodulation

I'm doing amplitude modulation and demodulation for DSB. the maximum amplitude of my original signal is $1$. After demodulating the signal, I should be getting the original signal which is $1$ but instead I am getting $0.8$.

So my question is where the other $0.2$ went ? is it considered as a noise ?

Comment: If you want any help, you should provide some context. What is your setup (hardware and software)? What are the oscilloscope traces / DSP plots of the signals at different stages? How are you modeling the RF channel? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your modulation index is probably 80%.  Since your modulation index is < 1.0, your demodulated signal will be scaled by the Modulation Index.  Look at each stage of your modulation/demodulation and you'll see that the modulated signal is 1 + modIndex * originalSignal.  When you demodulate, your signal will be modIndex * originalSignal.